# jQuery - Style checkbox, replace with image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need this script to hide my checkboxes and put an image of a styled checkbox in place of it. It is properly hiding it and showing the default image, but it will not update the checkbox to checked or unchecked once I click on it, nor will it update the image. I'm assuming it's a simple thing I am overlooking, I'm still new to jQuery.

Here is the script:

```
        $(".check").each(function() {
            $(this).hide();

            var $image = $("<img src='assets/images/layout/checkbox/unchecked.png' />").insertAfter(this);    

            $image.click(function() {
                var $checkbox = $(this).prev(".check");
                $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));

                if($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
                    $image.attr("src", "assets/images/layout/checkbox/checked.png");
                } else {
                    $image.attr("src", "assets/images/layout/checkbox/unchecked.png");
                }
            })
        });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
```

Edit: Also, is this generally the best approach to styling checkboxes? I can't seem to find anything that is much easier than this, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SaEYH/.

Comment: BTW: `$('.check')` == `$('input[type=checkbox]')`, so no need to set classes for jQuery.

Comment: I've removed all of the other jQuery scripts on the page and it's still not working, any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: A classic solution: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: you were missing a semicolon after the closed parentheses (2nd from the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was using a dated version of jQuery, which was the problem. I updated to 1.7.2 and everything worked as it should.

Comment: Source code works as it looks here. The version that worked was 1.7.2, but I don't know what it was at prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use this jQuery plugin called [Zebra_Transform](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-transform/) which transforms all the check boxes, radio buttons and select boxes on a page, it is very very small (3KB), and works in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several solutions and the best choice seems:
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ 
It is simple and works well.

Comment: Sadly Ryan Fait has passed away and this page is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Know this is an older thread -- but needed a solution to converting checkboxes to images -- and this was the best answer. :)  So refactored it some and wanted to share.

```
function setCheckboxImageSrc(checkbox, image, checkedUrl, uncheckedUrl) {
    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        image.attr("src", checkedUrl);
    } else {
        image.attr("src", uncheckedUrl);
    }
}

function setCheckboxImage(checkboxObj, className, checkedUrl, uncheckedUrl) {
    checkboxObj.hide();

    var $image = $("<img src='" + checkedUrl + "' />").insertAfter(checkboxObj);
    setCheckboxImageSrc(checkboxObj, $image, checkedUrl, uncheckedUrl);

    $image.click(function () {
        var $checkbox = $image.prev("." + className);
        $checkbox.click();
        setCheckboxImageSrc($checkbox, $image, checkedUrl, uncheckedUrl);
    });
}

$(".checkboxUp").each(function () {
    setCheckboxImage($(this), "checkboxUp", "../../../images/DirectionUpChecked.png", "../../../images/DirectionUpUnchecked.png");
});

$(".checkboxDown").each(function () {
    setCheckboxImage($(this), "checkboxDown", "../../../images/DirectionDownChecked.png", "../../../images/DirectionDownUnchecked.png");
});
```